# Why my lambdas do not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I struggle with making lambdas work. The code here is example, but it shows my problem well.

```
lambdas = list()

for i in range(5):
    lambdas.append(lambda x:i*i*x)


print lambdas[0](1)
print lambdas[2](1)
```

This give me 16, but I expect to have different value for different lambda. Why is happening!

Comment: "Scoping in Python is lexical. A closure will always remember the name and scope of the variable, not the object it's pointing to." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python Your lambda captures the name `i`, not the *object value* referenced by `i`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this code:

```
for i in range(5):
    lambdas.append(lambda x:i*i*x)
```

The value of `i` is determined when the function is *run*.  The value of `i` when the function is *defined* is lost.

Use instead:

```
lambdas = list()

for i in range(5):
    lambdas.append(lambda x, i=i : i*i*x)  

print lambdas[0](1)
print lambdas[2](1)
```

This produces:

```
0
4
```

This works because, as a special case, the default arguments to a function, as in `i=i` above, bind immediately.

Comment: An explanation as to why it didn't work originally would make this a great answer. But I really like the default argument instant bind.

Comment: @Serdalis Good idea.  Explanation added.

Answer (score 6):

`i` is  `4` when your loop ends so `i` is 4 for every `lambda`.

If you print `i` outside the loop you will see it is 4:

```
for i in range(5):
    lambdas.append(lambda x: i * i * x)

print(i)
4
```

You are using a variable that is being updated throughout the loop, if you call the lambda inside the loop you would get what you were expecting.

```
for i in range(5):
    lambdas.append(lambda x: i * i * x)
    print(lambda x: i * i * x)(1)
0
1
4
9
16
```

The behaviour is what you would expect, `i` is simply a variable like any other.

On a side note you could use a list comp to create your list:

```
lambdas = [lambda x,i=i: i * i * x for i in xrange(5)]
```